# What am I doing (simple uniform converge problem) $f_n(x)=n^2x^2e^{-xn}$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

consider the function $f_n(x)=n^2x^2e^{-xn}$ I am asked if it uniform converge on $A=(a,\infty) \quad a>0$

So it easy to see that in converge to $0$, but when I wanted to check uniform converge I noticed that the function getting maximum on $x=\frac{2}{n}$ pluging this value of $x$ to the function will give:

$f_n(\frac{2}{n})=\frac{4}{e^2}$, from here I concluded that $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|>0$

but this solution is wrong according to their solution, they actually used the same value of $x$ that I found to show it is uniform converge.they say for every $n>\frac{2}{a}$ u get that $\sup |f_n|=f_n(a)$ wich can indicates that is uniform converge, I actually not understand why we looking on $n>\frac{2}{a}$
I found specific $x$ that getting a value for the function so the supremum cannot be zero

Comment: When you say, "from here I concluded that $\sup |f_n(x) - f(x)| > 0$, you're basically taking the sup over the wrong variable.  Fix an $x$ and notice that $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ converges.

Comment: The function is defined on $(a,\infty)$. For $n$ large enough, $\frac2n <a$ and then $f$ is not defined on that point.

Comment: I pluged the $x=\frac{2}{n}$ and got a value none zero so how is possible that the suprimum will converge to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false that $\sup_{x\in[a,\infty)}|f_n(x)|=4e^{-2}$. This is true if $\frac2n\geqslant a$, but this only occurs for finitely many $n$'s. If $\frac2n<a$, then $f_n$ is strictly decreasing and it attains its maximum at $a$. That maximum is $n^2a^2a^{-na}$ and, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2a^2a^{-na}=0$, your sequence converges uniformly to $0$ indeed.

Comment: I am not sure I understood, how $\frac2n<a$ make us understand that $f_n$ is strictly decreasing?

Comment: Because, since $f_n'(x)=-n^3xe^{-n x}\left(x-\frac2n\right)$, if $a>\frac2n$, then every $x$ in $[a,\infty)$ is greater than $\frac2n$ and therefore $f'(x)<0$. So, $f$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: ohh, yes how did I miss that, thank you !

Comment: I'm glad I could help.